# How to compress the image to 70% in the Windows Store apps?

Tags: c#, windows-8, compression, windows-store-apps

In my application, i suppose to compress the image into 70% in Windows Store apps. I could find the following code snippet in the Windows Phone 8.

[How do I compress an image on Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318481/how-do-i-compress-an-image-on-windows-phone)

In the above link, i can make use of the SaveJpeg method to do the compression with the mentioned quality. Precisely i need the same scenario in the Windows Store apps. I have to compress the given image stream into 70% quality. Is there any way to achieve this in the Windows 8 apps ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349611/how-to-resize-image-in-c-sharp-winrt-winmd/13775824#13775824

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the link to compressed the image in windows store app.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj218354.aspx

Code sample is given in Javascript, which can be easily changed to c#.

This should work.